# Proving distance between a set and its supremum is zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $S$ is a bounded above set ant $t=SupS$ how do I prove that $dist(S,t)=0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: On the basis of *bounded above* I’m assuming that $S\subseteq\Bbb R$. By definition the distance from $t$ to $S$ is $\inf\{|t-s|:s\in S\}$, and since we know that $s\le t$ for all $s\in S$ (why?), we can simplify this to $\inf\{t-s:s\in S\}$. Obviously this distance is not negative (why?), so the real problem is to prove that it’s not positive.

Let $d=\inf_{s\in S}(t-s)$, and suppose that $d>0$. Let $x=t-\frac{d}2<t$. Is $x$ an upper bound for $S$?